# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when I upload values to my database from Excel?

Tags: excel, spring-mvc

I am developing a Spring web application. When I am fetching the values from an Excel sheet and uploading to my database, I am getting a NullPointerException, even though I'm validating the values.

In my Excel sheet, column 5 data is empty when I fetched the that column values, I am getting the NullPointerException. How to validate that column value?

Here's my code:

```
 try
    {
        if(getCellValue(row.getCell(4)).tostring()!="")
        {

        criterias.put("fullName",getCellValue(row.getCell(5)));
        Driver driver=genericDAO.getByCriteria(Driver.class, criterias);
        if(driver==null)
        {
        error = true;
        lineError.append("Invalid driver name, ");
        }
        else
        {
        eztoll.setDriver(driver);
         }
        }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    e.printstacktrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may your code works if use this code

```
 String val=(String) getCellValue(row.getCell(5));
    if(!(StringUtils.isEmpty(val)))
    {
     blah,blah,blah....!!!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception you are getting is purely because of `expression` in your `if condition`. In this `getCellValue(row.getCell(4)).tostring()` expression it is trying to call `toString()` method on `Null` values which causes NullPointerException.

Comment: I already know the reason of this exception is toString(),I just wanted how to avoid that exception,anyway i got a solution, Thanks for your suggestion